# Can I copy "not-on-PSN" games from PC back to my Vita?

Tags: ps-vita

There was an odd "glitch" a while back where all PSP and PSX digital games were "authorized" to download on the PS Vita. They all work, but some aren't available normally such as Spyro and Crash. I downloaded several of these due to the glitch, and would like to keep them.

I normally offload all my games to my PC and delete them from the Vita if I need more space on my memory card since I can copy them back over. But with these "unauthorized" (for Vita--I own these games) ones I'm not sure what happens if I copy to PC, delete and then try to copy them back. Will I be able to copy and play these games? I hope so, but I don't really want to try it myself.

Comment: I can not try this myself but from what I know of how region/device locking works for Sony, chances are this will not work if you copy them off as they would not be valid targets to be copied back. Again however, I have no way of testing this as I do not have those games.

Comment: @James not sure about that though, since the copy can be performed 100% offline. Not willing to find out myself though

Comment: I seem to recall hearing you can still play them if you have them, so I *think* they shouldn't care if you copy them on and off.  I have no way to test this, though.

Comment: as long as nothing Sony is in the middle of copying the files I would say its ok Ben, but if you are using some tool from Sony to move files off and on to the Vita then I would say they can scan the codes to see if they are valid for the device and that was likely the bug the fixed later one. Its just a matter of if its in this data flow path to do that validation as well.

Comment: It's unlikely this will be answered given the small sample group of both people who did this and people who post on Stack. So... unless you want to try it yourself and let us know. I would say your _safest bet_ without experimenting is to just get a second memory card switch back and forth between the two.

Comment: @BryanC. Hrm other memory card that's an idea. I have a spare 4GB from when I bought my Vita, I'll see if I can copy to and from that one while leaving it on my main card

Comment: @BenBrocka, please be sure to post your results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! I copied Crash and Spyro to PC from a PS Vita that already downloaded them, then copied them over to a brand new memory card with Content Manager. The games launch and run with no problem even when connected to the internet.

Note this only helps if you already have these games on a Vita memory card. Without the PSN glitch these games still can't be put onto a Vita from anything but a PC backup like this.